# How can I set a start and modified date with one SQL Update command?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a simple SQL Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserTest] 
(
    [UserTestId]    INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId]        INT      NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate]  DATETIME NULL,
    [StartedDate]   DATETIME NULL
);
```

I set the modified date like this:

```
UPDATE UserTest
SET    ModifiedDate = @ModifiedDate
WHERE  UserTestId = @UserTestId
AND    UserId = @UserId
```

But is there a way I can also set the `StartedDate` in the same SQL to the `@ModifiedDate` if the `StartedDate` is `NULL` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the COALESCE statement to set StartedDate to itself if it is not null, or @ModifiedDate if it is.

```
UPDATE UserTest
SET    ModifiedDate = @ModifiedDate,
       StartedDate = COALESCE(StartedDate, @ModifiedDate)
WHERE  UserTestId = @UserTestId
AND    UserId = @UserId
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Case statement as well.

```
UPDATE UserTest
SET    ModifiedDate = @ModifiedDate,
       StartedDate = CASE WHEN StartedDate IS NULL THEN @ModifiedDate ELSE StartedDate END
WHERE  UserTestId = @UserTestId
AND    UserId = @UserId
```

Answer (score 2):

And because you're on SQL Server 2012, you can also use `IIF`:

```
UPDATE UserTest
SET    ModifiedDate = @ModifiedDate,
       StartedDate = IIF(StartedDate IS NULL, @ModifiedDate, StartedDate)
WHERE  UserTestId = @UserTestId
AND    UserId = @UserId
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the option to use `ISNULL` as well

```
UPDATE UserTest
SET    ModifiedDate = @ModifiedDate,
       StartedDate = ISNULL(StartedDate, @ModifiedDate)
WHERE  UserTestId = @UserTestId
       AND    UserId = @UserId
```